# Using other version of JDBC driver

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, bukkit

I am having problems while using other version of JDBC SQLite than this one what is by default in Java. I have added dependendy of [this driver](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.25.2) to pom.xml and when I use `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database.db");` then I can not use any special features from this driver because java default one is loaded.

I am trying to use downloaded, upper version of "jdbc:sqlite" driver. I have exported driver's source into my project in intellij using maven but when I am using Class.forName("org.jdbc.sqlite"); (location that is in my project) then it does not work and DriverManager still uses different driver that has lower version. I need the newer version to use ON CONFLICT feature. My problem is that I do not know how to use my own "jdbc:sqlite" driver in my project to create Connection.

Comment: There is no default JDBC driver in Java (except the JDBC-ODBC bridge in older version of Java, but that only listens to `jdbc:odbc:`-prefixed JDBC urls). Your problem is probably a different one. Please post your code and describe your problem more clearly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am trying to use downloaded, upper version of `"jdbc:sqlite"` driver. I have exported driver's source into my project in intellij using maven but when I am using `Class.forName("org.jdbc.sqlite");` (location that is in my project) then it does not work and `DriverManager` still uses different driver that has lower version. I need bigger version to use `ON CONFLICT` feature. My problem is that I do not know how to use my own `"jdbc:sqlite"` driver in my project to create `Connection`.

Comment: Then you likely have both the old and the new version of the driver on the classpath. Remove the older one.

Comment: This older one is in java enviroment. I can not do it.

Comment: Java by default does not include sqlite. If somebody put the driver in the (deprecated) `lib/ext` folder of the JVM, it should be removed This is purely a deployment or classpath configuration problem.

Comment: So how can I use sqlite without having any libraries of it in jar and only JDK installed on machine? I did not have any JDBC library before and `DriverManager` did not have any problem with finding JDBC SQLite. I want to use latest version of SQLite but I do not know why `DriverManager` (of java) is using its own JDBC SQLite driver instead of this that I have exported in my project.

Comment: The only other explanation if you are 100% sure that you don't have another version of sqlite on your classpath is that you use a library that contains a shaded copy of SQLite. You may want to check the output of `connection.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` to see what jar or other classpath entry provides the connection.

Comment: I am using only Bukkit (developing minecraft server plugin) and apache commons (for some utilities)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bukkit includes an older version of the sqlite driver. You should use the maven shade plugin (or the [gradle shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow)) to bundle the new sqlite driver into your JAR and rename it to a new name inside of your JAR (such as by prepending your package's group name followed by ".repackaged.").

Comment: Thanks. That was it :)